UDP packets are not being received
I am trying to make an IOT device that clicks an image and sends it to my Flutter app via a mixture of BLE (used to send short signals like "ready to receive the images," etc.) and wifi (to transfer the images over UDP). The IOT device is hosted as a hotspot, and the Flutter app connects.
The system works perfectly fine on Samsung phones; however, when I tested on a OnePlus 11R and IQQO Z3, the image data packets were sent by the IOT device but not received on the devices.
Do you have any idea why this issue might be occurring?

Have you checked the logs of the devices that are not working? It could be that they are dropping traffic or individual packets if they are using different firewall settings, for example.
